# Multiple layers of folder inside the layout

Tags: android, layout

In my android project, I have a folder called layout to store all xml files for layout, but there is also a folder inside called layout_settings

layout---->layout_settings--->about.xml

In my code 
I have setContentView(R.XX.about). How do I set it such that reflect the about.xml inside layout_settings folder.

The reason I am doing is I don't want to scatter all the layout files into flat hierarchy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, **you can't configure or modify a folder structure in android packages res/layout** because they are `read only file system`.

```
The resources mechanism doesn't support subfolders in the layout directory, so you need to keep that hierarchy flat.
```

If you have to do like that just you can give a xml files name like, layout_setting.xml , layout_display.xml etc and use it.